# Extract text with regex

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to a regex pattern, because I want to extract a text from a website.

```
For Each m As Match In New Regex("[\d]{9,17}(?=[""])").Matches(RichTextBox2.Text)
    ListBox5.Items.Add(m.Value)
Next
```

I know, my current regex pattern can extract numbers (I need it also), but I don't know how can I extract a simple text.

Example:

> "name": "I want this.",
>
> "name": "and this one.",

Comment: You might be better of using HTML Agility pack: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Maybe, but If it possible, then I want to use regex.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/\b([\w\s]+)\b/g

You can check it at http://regex101.com

/:\s+"([\w\s.]+)"/g - if you only want the last part to match :)

Comment: Thank you. Your regex code doesn't work(can't extract my text.), but thanks for your link, I'll check it soon.

Comment: Well, I wrote it with the two examples you provided at Regex101 and I got four matches, so it works fine. Good luck!

Comment: \b([\w\s]+)\b (the actual regex

Comment: /g - the Global switch you need to provide

Comment: if you want to exclude "name", remove the \s in the group.

Comment: Sorry. You help me too much. :) Have a nice day.

Comment: I edited my post. I really deserve my credit now! ;-)

Comment: Sorry. Last question. /:\s+"([\w\s.]+)"/g It's looks very good, but I get indentifier expected error.